# MySQL first free number between exists values

Tags: mysql, sql

Problem: Get first free port for server between exists values. If there is not a free place then take the highest + 1.

Extra: If server_deleted=1 then we can take the free port. Also we should take the free port when there is a gap between values. We should include server_type in where clause. The min value is first port e.g. 9000.

Now my query looks:

```
SELECT server_port + 1
  FROM pro_servers s
 WHERE s.server_port <> 0
   AND s.server_type = 'ts3'
   AND s.server_deleted = 0
   AND NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT s1.server_port
            FROM pro_servers s1
           WHERE s1.server_port <> 0
             AND s1.server_type = 'ts3'
             AND s1.server_port = s.server_port + 1
             AND s1.server_deleted = 0
        )
 ORDER BY server_port LIMIT 1
```

I think there is better way to do it. This query executes very slow.

For example the first=minimum=lowest = 9000, next is 9002, 9003. We need to get the 9001. If we add 9001 then get 9004. The first value 9000 exists in the table.

SAMPLE DATA

```
+-----------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
| server_id | server_port | server_deleted | server_type |
+-----------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
|       151 |        9500 |              1 | teamspeak3  |
|      8459 |        9500 |              0 | teamspeak3  |
|       183 |        9501 |              1 | teamspeak3  |
|       264 |        9502 |              1 | teamspeak3  |
|      4155 |        9502 |              1 | teamspeak3  |
|      2707 |        9503 |              1 | teamspeak3  |
|      4160 |        9503 |              1 | teamspeak3  |
|       154 |        9504 |              1 | teamspeak3  |
|      4163 |        9504 |              1 | teamspeak3  |
|       285 |        9506 |              1 | teamspeak3  |
|      4167 |        9506 |              1 | teamspeak3  |
|      8454 |        9506 |              0 | teamspeak3  |
|       241 |        9507 |              1 | teamspeak3  |
|      4169 |        9507 |              1 | teamspeak3  |
|       188 |        9509 |              1 | teamspeak3  |
|      4177 |        9509 |              1 | teamspeak3  |
+-----------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
```

QUERY RESULT: 9501. When we used this port then next: 9502, 9503, 9504, 9505, 9507, 9508, 9509, 9510 etc.

Comment: EXPLAIN  plan? Do you have indexes?

Comment: First number := lowest number := minumum number ?

Comment: Please post a data sample and the expected query result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT data.sPort
FROM 
  ((SELECT (s.server_port + 1) sPort
  FROM pro_servers s
  LEFT JOIN pro_servers sp1 ON sp1.server_port = s.server_port + 1
  WHERE (sp1.server_port IS NULL)
  ORDER BY sPort)

  UNION ALL

  (SELECT s.server_port sPost
  FROM pro_servers s
   GROUP BY s.server_port
   HAVING COUNT(s.server_port) = SUM(s.server_deleted)
  ORDER BY sPort)) AS data
ORDER BY data.sPort
LIMIT 1
```

SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12ab1/2

***How it works***

1. Left Join `pro_servers` with `pro_servers` with `server_port = server_port + 1` join condition and take rows, where there is `null` in *the next* port. These rows shows first ports from every gap. The port Id can be taken as `server_port + 1`.
2. Take all deleted ports.
3. Union 1. and 2., order by `server_port` and take the first one.

There is one assumption for an answer - port with the lowest number is always taken. If it's not true, check that port separately (or add another `UNION ALL` to the query).

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` keyword for that.

Comment: DISTINCT OR UNION without ALL?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT s.server_port sPost`

Comment: Thank you, it is faster and better than my latest query.

Comment: I am not sure that is good solution. Probably it return always the first port. I have to go home after 14h work. I will check it tomorow.

Comment: You didn't provide any sample data , so you shouldn't expect any solution just work on your case! It's just an idea, which has to be specified to your situation: db tables structure, data stored there, etc.

Comment: I was very tired. I have added sample data and table structure. Take attention to 9505, 9508 which should be included into exit's results.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try to index the table.

CREATE INDEX indexName ON tableName(field1 [,field2...]);

Answer (score 0):

I would use this query that uses `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT MIN(server_port)+1
FROM pro_servers p1
WHERE
  p1.server_type = 'ts3' AND
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT server_port
              FROM   pro_servers p2
              WHERE  p1.server_port=p2.server_port-1
                     AND p1.server_type=p2.server_type
                     AND p2.server_deleted=0)
```

or this that uses a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT MIN(p1.server_port)+1
FROM
  pro_servers p1 LEFT JOIN pro_servers p2
  ON p1.server_port=p2.server_port-1
     AND p1.server_type=p2.server_type
     AND p2.server_deleted=0
WHERE
  p2.server_port IS NULL
  AND p1.server_type='ts3'
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff9b6/1).

Comment: We should not write the first port because it is related with server type.

Comment: @AdamMiaśkiewicz is the first value already there? pls see my updated answer. It is almost the same query as yours, I'm only using MAX() aggregate function instead of ORDER BY and LIMIT 1

Comment: Yes, the first value is already inserted. Yours queries are not fast as @MarcinJuraszek answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be faster but it will certainly help you to avoid repeating same conditions twice:

```
SELECT
  MAX(server_port) + 1 AS first_available_port
FROM (
  SELECT
    server_port,
    @row := @row + 1 AS row
  FROM
    pro_servers AS s,
    (SELECT @row := 0) AS x
  WHERE server_port <> 0
    AND server_type = 'ts3'
    AND server_deleted = 0
) AS s
GROUP BY
  server_port - row
ORDER BY
  server_port - row
LIMIT 1
;
```

The inner query enumerates existing ports matching the conditions. Now, the difference between the port numbers and the row numbers will stay the same for rows belonging to the same group of consecutive rows. The outer query groups by that difference and returns the first group's highest port plus one.