# MySQL add exception to exists query, SELECT the maximum value + 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a following script. It was been always working. Yesterday it started responding 0 results. I found the reason. The script do not select the highest port and add 1 when there is not between free ports. How to add the exception or fix it if it is exists already.

It should select at first free server port (from deleted servers) or if not exists then the latest one + 1.

How it works: [MySQL first free number between exists values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396545/mysql-first-free-number-between-exists-values)

```
SELECT data.sPort
    FROM 
      ((SELECT (s.server_port + 1) sPort
      FROM servers s
      LEFT JOIN servers sp1 ON sp1.server_port = s.server_port + 1
      WHERE (sp1.server_port IS NULL) AND sp1.server_port<>0 AND sp1.server_type='" . $server['server_type'] . "' AND sp1.server_port<>9987
      ORDER BY sPort)

      UNION ALL

      (SELECT s.server_port sPost
      FROM servers s
    WHERE s.server_port<>0  AND s.server_port<>9987 AND s.server_type='" . $server['server_type'] . "'
       GROUP BY s.server_port
       HAVING COUNT(s.server_port) = SUM(s.server_deleted)
      ORDER BY sPort)) AS data
    ORDER BY data.sPort
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `WHERE (sp1.server_port IS NULL) AND sp1.server_port<>0 AND sp1.server_type='" ...` Does not compute ... Hint: `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first derived table it seems that you want to select the next port for a specific server type. If so, try changing this

```
LEFT JOIN servers sp1 ON sp1.server_port = s.server_port + 1
WHERE (sp1.server_port IS NULL) AND sp1.server_port<>0 AND sp1.server_type='" . $server['server_type'] . "' AND sp1.server_port<>9987
```

to

```
LEFT JOIN servers sp1 ON sp1.server_port = s.server_port + 1 
  AND s.server_type = sp1.server_type
WHERE sp1.server_port IS NULL
  AND s.server_port<>0 
  AND s.server_type='" . $server['server_type'] . "' 
  AND s.server_port<>9987
```